# What is the content of Hogwarts letters received by students at the beginning of a term?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

I wanted to know that through his 6 years of education Harry received letters from Hogwarts at the beginning of his term and if Hogwarts wasn't taken over by death eaters he would still receive a letter for his 7th year. Does anyone know the contents of those letters and what did they say in particular.

Comment: A list with the books to buy was in it.

Comment: And any other new supplies needed for the year.

Answer (score 20):

Harry's **First Year letter** was an invitation to Hogwarts signed by Professor McGonagall;

> *Dear Mr Potter, We are pleased to inform you that you have a place at
>   Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find enclosed a
>   list of all necessary books and equipment. Term begins on 1 September.
>   We await your owl by no later than 31 July.*
>
> *Yours sincerely,*
>
> *Minerva McGonagall
>
>   Deputy Headmistress*

It also contained an [extensive list of items](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Hogwarts_acceptance_letter) he'd need to acquire before joining which included a wand and a familiar.

---

The sole mention of his **Second Year letter** is in the following passage;

> *‘Letters from school,’ said Mr Weasley, passing Harry and Ron
>   identical envelopes of yellowish parchment, addressed in green ink.
>   ‘Dumbledore already knows you’re here, Harry – doesn’t miss a trick,
>   that man. You two’ve got them, too,’ he added, as Fred and George
>   ambled in, still in their pyjamas.*
>
> *For a few minutes there was silence as they all read their letters.
>   Harry’s told him to catch the Hogwarts Express as usual from King’s
>   Cross station on September the first.*
>
> *There was also a list of the new
>   books he’d need for the coming year.*

The list of books included Miranda Goshawk's 'Standard Book of Spells, Grade 2' and a wide variety of Gilderoy Lockhart texts

---

Harry's **Third Year letter** was seen in full, but the attached list of books and permission form were not;

> *Dear Mr Potter,
>   Please note that the new school year will begin on September the first. The Hogwarts Express will leave from King’s Cross Station, platform nine and three-quarters, at eleven o’clock.
>
>   Third-years are permitted to visit the village of Hogsmeade at certain weekends. Please give the enclosed permission form to your parent or guardian to sign.
>
>   A list of books for next year is enclosed.
>
>   Yours sincerely,
>
>   Professor M. McGonagall
>
>   Deputy Headmistress*

We know from later mentions that the book list included the "Monster Book of Monsters" and "Unfogging the Future" amongst other texts.

---

Harry's **Fourth Year letter** is seen only briefly and confirms the need for formal clothes and at least one spellbook;

> *‘What?’ said Ron, looking horror-struck.
>
>   ‘Dress robes!’ repeated Mrs Weasley. ‘It says on your school list that you’re supposed to have dress robes this year … robes for formal occasions.’*

His book list also contained at least one item.

> *Harry started unwrapping the shopping. Apart from The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 4, by Miranda Goshawk, he had a handful of new quills, a dozen rolls of parchment and refills for his potion-making kit*

<sub><sup>h/t to Au101 for finding these references</sup></sub>

---

Harry's **Fifth year letter** confirms the start date of term. There's also an addendum with two additional books;

> *‘Booklists have arrived,’ he said, throwing one of the envelopes up to Harry, who was standing on a chair. ‘About time, I thought they’d forgotten, they usually come much earlier than this …’*
>
> *Harry swept the last of the droppings into a rubbish bag and threw the bag over Ron’s head into the wastepaper basket in the corner, which swallowed it and belched loudly. He then opened his letter. It contained two pieces of parchment: one the usual reminder that term started on the first of September; the other telling him which books he would need for the coming year.*
>
> *‘Only two new ones,’ he said, reading the list, ‘The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 5, by Miranda Goshawk, and Defensive Magical Theory, by Wilbert Slinkhard.’*

Notably, Ron and Hermione's letters contains a confirmation that they'd been made Prefect and their badges.

---

Harry's **Sixth year letter** is tersely mentioned;

> *The day after this rather gloomy birthday tea, their letters and book
>   lists arrived from Hogwarts. Harry’s included a surprise: he had been
>   made Quidditch Captain.*
>
> *‘That gives you equal status with prefects!’ cried Hermione happily.
>   ‘You can use our special bathroom now, and everything!’*

---

For obvious reasons, Harry didn't receive a **Seventh Year letter.**

Comment: Great answer but you're not quite right about the Goblet of Fire In *Weasley's Wizard Wheezes* at the end of the chapter, Mrs Weasley asks harry to leave his school list out so she can get his things along with everyone elses. That list, as we see in *Mayhem at the Ministry*, requires them to have dress robes. it's also implied that the only book on the book list was *The Standard Book of Spells, Grade 4*, all the information you need is in *Mayhem at the Ministry*, pp.138-9 of the original Bloomsbury edition

Answer (score 4):

The real first year letter read:

> Dear Mr. Potter,
>
> We are pleased to inform you that you have been accepted at Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry. Please find and enclosed list of all necessary books and equipment.
>   Term begins on September 1. We await your owl by no later than July 31.
>   Yours sincerely,
>
> [signed]
>
> Minerva Mcgonagall,
>   *Deputy Headmistress*
> <sup>*-Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone, Chapter Four (The Keeper of the Keys).*</sup>

By the way, I know this is true because I got it from the book.

Here's a screenshot from the e-copy of the book:

[image: Screenshot of e-book copy of *Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone depicting the above mentioned "invitation letter"]

Comment: Welcome =) Thanks for your input, i'm not really sure how your version of the 1st year letter differs from Valorum's?

Comment: @Au101 It contains a screenshot of the letter. No additional information, but still a nice gimmick imho.